# Time spent in each calendar year

Tags: r, date

I followed some individuals A and B from start to end

```
df<-data.frame(id=c("A", "B"), start=as.Date(c("2015-01-01", "2013-01-01")), end=as.Date(c("2021-06-12", "2017-10-10")))
df

  id      start        end
1  A 2015-01-01 2021-06-12
2  B 2013-01-01 2017-10-10
```

I would like to calculate the the follow up time for each calendar year. For example I have 1 year for 2013 (from B), 1 year for 2014 (from B),  2 years for 2015 (from A and B) and so on.

I tried to treat year as an integer and count how many years each individual contributes but due to rounding errors the result is not plausible.

I tried

```
years<-NULL

for (i in 1:length(df$id)){
  years<-c(years, as.character(as.Date(seq.Date(from = df$start[i], to = df$end[i], by = "day"))))
}
library(lubridate)
table(year(years))/365

 2013      2014      2015      2016      2017      2018      2019      2020      2021 
1.0000000 1.0000000 2.0000000 2.0054795 1.7753425 1.0000000 1.0000000 1.0027397 0.4465753
```

which is the answer I am trying to get but is computationally inefficient and very slow in large data. I am wondering is there any way to do this without the loop? Or do it more efficiently?

Comment: Do you want `table(unlist(do.call(mapply, c(\`:\`, lapply(df[-1], \(x) as.numeric(format(x, "%Y")))))))`?

Comment: something like this but it does not seem to handle partial years (2021 and 2017)

Comment: If you have special requirements for *partial years*, please be clear about it in your question, as it is not obvious what you think it should be. Rounding? Ceiling/floor? Fractional? (Probably not fractional, you did say *"integer"*.)

Comment: Thank you. Now I provide a solution which is correct but computationally inefficient . Maybe I could get a comment how to make it more efficient.

Comment: How can you have more than 2 years of follow-up time in 2016? I suspect your assumption of "correct" is premature. Look at the note in my answer about leap-years, your hard-coded use of `365` is provably incorrect. If you truly want fractional years, then you need to [edit] your question and change *"treat year as an integer and count"* to something more representative.

Comment: You are right. It has to do with leap years. But its good enough and so will be any other solution. I did not ask to treat year as integer, I said I tried to treat as integer but the rounding errors were very high.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm now guessing what you actually don't want to round or truncate anything, so here's a solution that works and gives output similar to your method (correcting the 2016 value):

```r
func <- function(st, ed) {
  stopifnot(length(st) == 1, length(ed) == 1)
  stL <- as.POSIXlt(st)
  edL <- as.POSIXlt(ed)
  start_year <- 1900 + stL$year
  end_year <- 1900 + edL$year
  start_eoy <- as.POSIXlt(paste0(start_year, "-12-31"))
  end_eoy <- as.POSIXlt(paste0(end_year, "-12-31"))
  firstyear <- (start_eoy$yday - stL$yday) / start_eoy$yday
  lastyear <- edL$yday / end_eoy$yday
  data.frame(
    year = seq(start_year, end_year),
    n = c(firstyear, rep(1, max(0, end_year - start_year - 1)), lastyear)
  )
}
```

### base R

```r
aggregate(n ~ year, data = do.call(rbind, Map(func, df$start, df$end)), FUN = sum)
#   year         n
# 1 2013 1.0000000
# 2 2014 1.0000000
# 3 2015 2.0000000
# 4 2016 2.0000000
# 5 2017 1.7747253
# 6 2018 1.0000000
# 7 2019 1.0000000
# 8 2020 1.0000000
# 9 2021 0.4450549
```

### dplyr

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  with(Map(func, start, end)) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarize(n = sum(n))
# # A tibble: 9 x 2
#    year     n
#   <int> <dbl>
# 1  2013 1    
# 2  2014 1    
# 3  2015 2    
# 4  2016 2    
# 5  2017 1.77 
# 6  2018 1    
# 7  2019 1    
# 8  2020 1    
# 9  2021 0.445
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I provide a solution which is correct but computationally inefficient . Maybe I could get a comment how to make it more efficient.

Comment: OP: I believe @r2evans has provided a correct answer to the questioin you asked.  If you now have a follow up question about the efficiency of the answer, then I believe the appropriate thing to do is to accept the answer provided here, attempt to optimise the solution yourself and then, if unsuccessful, post another question and provide details of the way in which the solution does not meet your needs.

Comment: @Limey the answer is nformtunately not correct. floor, ceiling lead to great rounding errors

Comment: ECII, check the updates please, I think it's better at inferring what you need.

Comment: Perfect solution. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a job for a great package called `lubridate`. See example:

By the way, I assumed dates are year-month-day, therefore `ymd`. If not, you can use `ydm` (year-day-month) for American date format.

```r
df<-data.frame(id=c("A", "B"), start=as.Date(c("2015-01-01", "2013-01-01")), end=as.Date(c("2021-06-12", "2017-10-10")))

library(lubridate)
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'lubridate'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
#> 
#>     date, intersect, setdiff, union
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(across(start:end, ymd),
           follow_up_years = interval(start, end)/years(1),
           follow_up_months = interval(start, end)/months(1),
           follow_up_days = interval(start, end)/days(1),
    )
#>   id      start        end follow_up_years follow_up_months follow_up_days
#> 1  A 2015-01-01 2021-06-12        6.443836         77.36667           2354
#> 2  B 2013-01-01 2017-10-10        4.772603         57.29032           1743
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

**Edit**

I think I understand. I guess we can also just use lubridate intervals:

```r
df %>%
    mutate(follow_up_2015 = interval(start, as_date("2015-01-01"))/years(1)) %>%
    pull(follow_up_2015) %>%
    sum()
#> [1] 2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Ok but this doesnt answer my question. How many years of follow up do I have in 2015?